# Inline SVG background image does not work in React.js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg

I have a component that should provide a div with a dot grid pattern.

The function that should do the work looks like this:

```
drawSquareDotGrid(distance, unit, colour){      
        var newGrid = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width=\""+distance+unit+"\" height=\""+distance+unit+"\"><circle cx=\"4mm\" cy=\"4mm\" r=\"0.3mm\" fill=\""+colour+ "\"/></svg>"
        this.setState({grid: newGrid })
    }
```

and this is my render function:

```
  render() {
    const windowHeight = window.innerHeight - 105
    const sx = {width: "100%",
                height: windowHeight,
                backgroundImage: 'url('+ this.state.grid +')'}
    return (
        <div style={sx}></div>
    )
  }
```

The string with SVG does not appear in generated HTML however it somewhat works if I use simpler SVG like this:

```
var newGrid = "data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg><circle></svg>"
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you!

Rosta

Comment: Try to encode special characters. To do so, you can use `window.encodeURIComponent`

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you for your answer. I tried to use this function to both the whole string and special characters only. It does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: @Kaiido Turned out you was right after all + there were missing viewPort and xlmns from SVG header. Thanks once again :)

Comment: @Kaiido if you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: You can checkout [this article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-svg-patterns/) for using SVG (backgrounds) in React.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kaiido pointed out URI should be encoded with `window.encodeURIComponent`. Also there were missing xlmns and viewPort information in the SVG header.

Fixed code looks like this:

```
drawSquareDotGrid(distance, unit, colour){ 
    var prefix = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,"
    var grid = "<svg width=\""+distance+unit+"\" height=\""+distance+unit+"\" viewPort=\"0 0 5mm 5mm\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"><circle cx=\"4mm\" cy=\"4mm\" r=\"0.3mm\" fill=\""+colour+ "\"/></svg>"
    var newGrid = prefix + window.encodeURIComponent(grid)
    this.setState({grid: newGrid })
}
```